# Send Tracking via Marketing Rest Api - Track individual Subscriber results?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Is it possible to GET tracking stats for sent emails via the Marketing Cloud Rest Api?

I can send an email via POST using messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/{triggeredSendId}/send .  I am returned a response containing a requestId.

I can GET a summary of the tracking information for this particular triggeredSendId from messaging/v1/messageSends/{triggeredSendId}/summary .

I can also GET delivery records for this particular triggeredSendId from messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/{triggeredSendId}/deliveryRecords/ .

I do not seem to be able to figure out to get an more granular on a per Subscriber basis.

The messaging/v1/rest endpoint gives me information about additional calls.  I see there is one to messageSends/{id}/deliveryRecords/{rid} with rid being the requestId.  When I pass the api the requestId returned by my initial send, I recieve a 404.

A GET to messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/{triggeredSendId}/feeds/deliveryRecords returns a response containing deliveryTime, requestId, status, and the to address.

A GET to messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/{triggeredSendId}/deliveryRecords reutns a response with roughly the same information.

A GET to messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/{triggeredSendId}/deliveryRecords/{requestId} return the same information as the above 2 calls on a per record basis.

Is there any way to retrieve the tracking information provided by messaging/v1/messageSends/{triggeredSendId}/summary on a per individual Subscriber basis rather than the aggregate totals for a triggeredSendId?

Thanks.

Mike

Comment: I believe this kind of information is only available via SOAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear what I am attempting to do is possible using the REST Api.

This will have to be accomplished via SOAP or via an data extract to FTP.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so here is how I would do it.  I would write a query activity to run in an automation within Automation Studio, which as a result would have my data segmented as desired to a DE.  I would then do a SOAP call to do a RETRIEVE on that DE.  You could also do something in landing pages if security isn't that big a deal.